# How to stop code from continuing onto particular section once IF statement has been fullfilled?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have multiple `IF` statements, that I want execute but once the logic for any of the IF statements has been fulfilled I want the code to skip over a particular section that is not included in any of the IF` statements.

How do I do this?

How code is setup currently:

```
 if 1 in df.index:
        if df.col1.isnull()[1] or (df.col1[1]==''):
           [rest of the code]

 if 2 in df.index:
        if df.col1.isnull()[2] or (df.col1[2]==''):
           [rest of the code]

 if 3 in df.index:
        if df.col1.isnull()[3] or (df.col1[3]==''):
           [rest of the code]


[code I want to skip once any of the IF statements have been fulfilled]

[code I need to run regardless]
```

Comment: make sure you posted a proper indentation, now it looks like the 2nd `if` is IN the 1st one

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest good eye thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if` for the first if statement then use `elif` for the rest or wrap each of the `if` statements in a `try` and `except` statement

Comment: There is no reason to use try-except in this particular situation

Answer (score 1):

You can use if, elif construct for you logic building however as you have mentioned that you want to skip/run a particular part of the code which is not a part of the any if block, depending on some cases fulfilled inside any if block then you can use a flag to flip its value inside the if block.

```
flag = True;
if condition1:
  flag = False

if flag:
  code to be skipped
```